# ActionScript newbie, need some help

Tags: actionscript-3

I started learning flash and actionscript very recently and I am having fun with it. Now, here's something I wanna do with actionscript and since I am pretty new, I am not yet sure where to look for to learn what I want. I am specifically looking for image manipulation techniques that can be achieved with AS, for example, basic image manipulation like changing contrast/brightness, transform image etc. Can anyone guide me towards any relevant tutorial/resources that would be easy to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these pages:

http://gotoandlearn.com/index.php?currentpage=5

http://gotoandlearn.com/index.php?currentpage=6

Watch the videos titled:

Introduction to Pixel Bender: Part 1

Introduction to Pixel Bender: Part 2

Animating Pixel Bender Filters

This will have you well on your way. The rest of the site is packed with hundreds of free videos + source files (in many cases) so you should be well on your way with this website. The tutorials on that website are actually my foundation/roots/beginnings in flash. Of course since then I've moved on to more advanced topics/theory etc but there is more than enough information to come out a real flash developer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend buying the book [Learning Actionscript 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652787X). This is the book I started with and to be honest I never needed another book on Actionscript again. It covers pretty much everything, including image manipulation.

You can see and download the samples from the book [here](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/downloads/). For image manipulation, I would recommend looking at example of 'Drawing With Pixels'.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good books out there. Colin Moock's [Essential Actionscript](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526948) is by far my favorite book.

If your looking for some online help or tutorials heres a list of references:

A nice tutorial on [active tuts](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-brightness-editor-in-actionscript-3/) for changing the brightness of an image.

Senocular is an AWESOME reference in anything flash. [Here](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) he talks about the Matrix class is basically any size manipulation to a movieclip of image.

Finally the Adobe live docs are the best place for you to learn the built in classes AS3 has to offer. the [Movieclip.transform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#transform) property is the basis for all aspects of image manipulation (hue,tint,etc).

Good luck in your learning, I remember how exciting it was for me!